# Using Jetty's proxy in standalone Jetty application

Tags: proxy, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

I'm investigating using Jetty 9 as a proxy, using standalone Jetty, not embedded Jetty. I've looked for help in many places:

Most of these are related to embedded Jetty:

- [How to create Proxy Server using jetty8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596668/how-to-create-proxy-server-using-jetty8)
- [Jetty ProxyServlet with SSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852056/jetty-proxyservlet-with-ssl-support)

This question is along the same lines:

- [Can stand-alone Jetty be used as a reverse proxy (without Apache mod-proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442798/can-stand-alone-jetty-be-used-as-a-reverse-proxy-without-apache-mod-proxy)

...but the only answer is a link to a page that covers some parameters for the proxy, but no examples or other helpful hints.

On to the question...

I've created an extension to Jetty's ProxyServlet, which overrides the `rewriteURI()` method to actually change the request to a different URL. This custom proxy works when running Jetty embedded, but when I use a web.xml file and the jetty-maven-plugin to create a war to deploy, it no longer works.

When I make a request, I can debug the application and see that it gets into the `rewriteURI()` method, it then calls Jetty's ProxyServlet's `service()` method, which runs to completion, but then nothing happens. The page remains blank, and eventually ProxyServlet's `onResponseFailure()` is called with a TimeoutException, "Total timeout elapsed". Dev tools shows the request receiving a 504 Gateway Timeout.

It seems as though something is missing in how things are connected, but I can't tell what it might be. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've included `web.xml` and the custom proxy (`ProxyServletExtension`) below.

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.example.ProxyServletExtension</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**ProxyServletExtension.java**

```
...
import org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet;
...
public class ProxyServletExtension extends ProxyServlet {
    @Override
    protected URI rewriteURI(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Forward all requests to another port on this machine
        String uri = "http://localhost:8060";

        // Take the current path and append it to the new url
        String path = request.getRequestURI();
        uri += path;

        // Add query params
        String query = request.getQueryString();
        if (query != null && query.length() > 0) {
            uri += "?" + query;
        }
        return URI.create(uri).normalize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the hints I needed to solve this with [jetty transparent proxy always returns 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027679/jetty-transparent-proxy-always-returns-403-forbidden?rq=1). The question didn't exactly pertain to my question, but the code snippet provided showed me what I needed in the `<servlet>` in `web.xml`.

**Updated web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.example.ProxyServletExtension$Transparent</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>proxyTo</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8060</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>proxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Required changes**

1. Set the `<servlet-class>` to `ProxyServletExtension$Transparent`, previously I wasn't using a trasparent proxy.
2. Use an `<init-param>` of `proxyTo` using the address you would like to proxy the requests to. This also means that the `ProxyServletExtension.java` class above (in the question) is completely unnecessary.

Also, it is worth mentioning that there is a `prefix` `<init-param>` as well, which can be used to remove part of the incoming request before proxying to the proxied request.